# Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Observable<Geoposition>'. Google Maps

Tags: rxjs, ionic3, ionic-native, rxjs6

I have a taxi booking app that uses Ionic Geolocation and Firebase Firestore. My code was not working with the firestore package so i had to update rxjs to version 6. It brought up the error

```
'Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Observable<Geoposition>'. '
```

Here is my code

```
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';



    const subscription = this.geo.watchPosition()
                          .filter((p) => p.coords !== undefined) //Filter Out Errors
                          .subscribe(position => {
                          let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                          this.map.setCenter(latLng);
                          this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
                          this.long = position.coords.longitude;
                          console.log(this.long + ' ' + this.lat);
});
```

my package.json file

```
"@ionic-native/core": "~4.15.0",
"@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.17.0",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.15.0",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.15.0",
"@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
"angularfire2": "^5.1.0",
"cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.1",
"firebase": "^5.5.7",
"ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
"ionic-native": "^2.9.0",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"rxjs": "^6.3.3",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Use pipeable operators: https://angular.io/guide/rx-library, https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Comment: @JBNizet how do i use that?

Comment: As described, with examples and everything, in the two pages I linked to.

Comment: @JBNizet sorry for that noob question, fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @JB Nizet and @martin for their contributions. I just remembered that in the latest versions of rxJs you have to use the .pipe operator when chaining txjs operators like filters and map. here is my updated code

```
const subscription = this.geo.watchPosition()
                          .pipe(filter((p) => p.coords !== undefined)) //Filter Out Errors
                          .subscribe(position => {
                          let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                          this.map.setCenter(latLng);
                          this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
                          this.long = position.coords.longitude;
                          console.log(this.long + ' ' + this.lat);
});
```